# MIT APP INVENTOR 2 dictionary trouble

Tags: app-inventor

MIT APP INVENTOR 2 I have this problem: I have a dictionary with many sub-classes. But I have no idea how I could access to specific data inside the dictionary. For example a have the next list:

```
{
  "keystatus" : "valid",
  "status" : 0,
  "result" : [
    {
      "stores" : {
        "0" : {
          "category" : "",
          "min_price" : "64.90",
          "manufacturer" : "adidas",
          "url" : "https:\/\/www.rakuten.de\/%20produkt%20\/adidas-leonero-herrenschuhe-sneaker-2040331525.html?portaldv=6",
          "title" : "adidas Leonero Herrenschuhe Sneaker",
          "advertiser" : "Rakuten Deutschland GmbH",
          "currency" : "€",
          "max_price" : ""
        }
      },
      "details" : {
        "barcode_formats" : "EAN 4058025901204",
        "color" : "",
        "publisher" : "",
        "weight" : "",
        "actor" : "",
        "brand" : "adidas",
        "product_name" : "adidas Leonero Herrenschuhe Sneaker",
        "category" : "",
        "prod_details" : "",
        "manufacturer" : "adidas",
        "length" : "",
        "label" : "",
        "clothing_size" : "",
        "artist" : "",
        "height" : "",
        "model" : "",
        "width" : "",
        "director" : "",
        "genre" : "",
        "manufacturer_part_number" : "Adidas Leonero",
        "long_description" : "Nach 70 Jahren als einer der weltbesten Hersteller von FuBballschuhen hat adidas jede Menge Erfahrung gesammelt, wenn es um cleanen Sportstyle geht. Wir haben uns von einigen der legendärsten Designs aus unseren Archiven inspirieren lassen und m",
        "features" : "",
        "author" : ""
      },
      "reviews" : {

      },
      "type" : "EAN",
      "images" : {
        "0" : "https:\/\/images.barcodelookup.com\/9152\/91526482-1.jpg"
      },
      "barcode" : "4058025901204"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to access to this part of the dictionary `["result"][0]["stores"]["0"]["title"]` . Any thoughts?

All ideas are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Write some code. If the code doesn't work, we can all stare at it and help you. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to learn how to work with lists and list of lists...

See these examples:
[How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj
[How to work with Lists and Lists of lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)
JSON and list of lists: [example1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/OGSe2a3X0fk/sVL8Adh1MHkJ) and [example2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/O5XpZEpM7zY/RlfTPifnCQAJ)